# .htaccess issue. My site cannot sign up and loading never stop

Tags: php, .htaccess

I purchased OKDating script from codecanyon and developer never show up support his own script. I install the website and support to signup account first time to get admin access and sign up process keep loading and never stop. Some other say that it is because of .htaccess issue and I don't have any idea to fix it.
I use AWS EC2 server and site name "www.chitthu.co"

Comment: Add your code with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is going to "http://www.chitthu.co/user/create" but is should go "http://www.chitthu.co/index.php/user/create"

To prevent this, hide index.php from the URL. Place below code in your root .htaccess file.

For PHP version above than 5.2.6 :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

For PHP version below than 5.2.6 :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

> mod_rewrite must be enabled with PHP.

Comment: I do with .htacess and then enable mod_rewrite at EC2 at AWS and it is get Internal Server Error and my website is down... What should I do?